# I tried this code in order to index, search and parse the csv tweets

Tags: java, parsing, search, indexing, lucene

I tried this code in order to index, search and parse the csv tweets but when executing  The fields of the first tweets are not displayed and the search class does not work, someone can help me please

```
   import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
class TweetDoc {
    protected static  String ID = "id";
    protected static String MAT="mat";
    protected static  String DATE = "date";
    protected static  String QUERY = "query";
    protected static  String USER = "user";
    protected static  String TEXT = "text";

TweetDoc(  String i,String m, String d, String q, String u, String t) {

                TweetDoc.ID=i;
                TweetDoc.MAT=m;
                TweetDoc.DATE = d;
                TweetDoc.QUERY=q;
                TweetDoc.USER = u;
                TweetDoc.TEXT=t;

                }}
public class Lucenetweet {
    public static final String INDEX_DIR = "D:\\Tweets\\index";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {

    if (args.length == 0) {
//READ FROM FILES
        BufferedReader reader = null ;
                int count = 0;




        try {

            File file = new File("D:\\Tweets\\collection\\tweets.csv");
            while (file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Reading from file '" + file + "'...");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                // Read every line in the file, and parse each tweet.
                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    count++; //Count number of tweets
                   System.out.println("Tweets = " + count);
                  Scanner s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\",\"");
                       String ID=s.next();
                       String MAT=s.next();
                       String DATE = s.next();
                       String QUERY = s.next();
                   String USER = s.next();
                       String TEXT=s.next();

                       String i= TweetDoc.ID;
                       System.out.println("l'identificateur est: " +i); 
                       String d=TweetDoc.DATE;
                       System.out.println("la date est :" +d);
                       String m=TweetDoc.MAT;
                       System.out.println("la matricule est :" +m );
                       String t=TweetDoc.TEXT;
                       System.out.println("le texte est: " +t);

                  TweetDoc tweet1 = new TweetDoc( ID,MAT, DATE, QUERY, USER, TEXT);    
                  index(tweet1);

                }

                    reader.close();
                System.out.println("Current number of tweets = " + count);
                //file_no++;
                //file = new File("D:\\tweet\\collection\\tweet"+file_no+".csv");

            }

        }
catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {

           try {
                reader.close();
                System.out.println("Total number of tweets = " + count);
            }
           catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}


        }
    }
public static void index (TweetDoc tweet) {
        File index = new File(INDEX_DIR);
        IndexWriter writer = null;

        try {   
            IndexWriterConfig indexConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
            writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(index), indexConfig);
            Document luceneDoc = new Document();
            //luceneDoc.add(new Field("POLARITY", tweet.POLARITY, Field.Index.NO));
                        //luceneDoc.add(new Field("ID", TweetDoc.ID, Field.Index.NO));
                        luceneDoc.add(new Field("DATE", tweet.DATE, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
                        //luceneDoc.add(new Field("QUERY", tweet.QUERY, Field.Index.NO));
            luceneDoc.add(new Field("USER", tweet.USER, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
            luceneDoc.add(new Field("TEXT", tweet.TEXT, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            //luceneDoc.add(new Field("ptitle", tweet.ptitle, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            luceneDoc.setBoost((float)2.0);
            writer.addDocument(luceneDoc);
} catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (writer !=null)
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }
 public static String[] search (String queryString, int topk) throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {

        IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_DIR)));
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        QueryParser queryparser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "TEXT", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
    try {
            StringTokenizer strtok = new StringTokenizer(queryString, " ~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|:;'<>,./?\"\'\\/\n\t\b\f\r");
            String querytoparse = " ";
            while(strtok.hasMoreElements()) {
                String token = strtok.nextToken();
                      querytoparse += "text:" + token;
}       
            Query query = queryparser.parse(querytoparse);
            System.out.println(query.toString());
            TopDocs results = indexSearcher.search(query, topk);
            int num_results = results.scoreDocs.length;
            System.out.println(num_results);
            String[] returnTweets = new String[num_results];
            for (int i = 0; i < num_results; i++) {
                                String temp = "@" + indexSearcher.doc(results.scoreDocs[i].doc).getFieldable("USER").stringValue();
                String DATE = indexSearcher.doc(results.scoreDocs[i].doc).getFieldable("DATE").stringValue();
                DATE = DATE.replace("+0000", "");
                temp += ": " + indexSearcher.doc(results.scoreDocs[i].doc).getFieldable("QUERY").stringValue();
                temp += "<br/>" + DATE + "    Score: " +  results.scoreDocs[i].score;;
                System.out.println(indexSearcher.doc(results.scoreDocs[i].doc).getFieldable("TEXT").stringValue());
                System.out.println("score: " + results.scoreDocs[i].score);
                returnTweets[i] = temp;

            }


            return returnTweets;            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            indexSearcher.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I put it or I remove it, it is the same thing

Comment: Why are you using version 3.6? Why not latest version?